# Virtual Hard Disk Migration from Virtual Server 2005 to Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtualhost

I have two questions,

1. Can I use existing 2nd Hard Drive as External Hard Drive inside Virtual Server Instance running on same machine?
2. If I use right now Virtual Server 2005 and run my server, tomorrow if I buy HyperV on different machine, can I just simply use same Virtual Hard Drive in Hyper V Without having to reinstall everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - If this hard drive is USB, then you will not be able to access it in a guest.  Virtual Server does not support USB from the guest operating system.

2 - Yes, Hyper-V will read your Virtual Server 2005 VHD files.  This is essentially how we migrated from VS2005 to Hyper-V by manually attaching the VHD files to new machine configurations.  You will need to uninstall the old guest service and install the new Hyper-V guest services for everything to work smoothly though.

Comment: +1 - Uninstalling the VMAdditions before you make the move is the key here.  If you don't do that, things quickly could get painful.

Comment: And there's no going back, I believe I read at one point that once Hyper-V puts its stamp on that VHD, it's upgraded, and won't be usable on the 2005 server.

Comment: Thanks, but we have not installed vmadditions and we dont need it either, i am not aware if anything gets installed automatically or not, but as long as we setup vhd, access via network and dont install anything onto it, its good to go right.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a .VHD on the external drive and use it - However be aware you can have your disk drivers load after Hyper-V tries to start and get errors - I never use external drives but that problem goes back to window service dependancies and was a common question in the early days of Virtual Server.

Steve Radich - http://www.VirtualServerFAQ.com - http://www.BitShop.com